# Does Windows XP have any built-in IMEs?

Tags: windows-xp, ime

I’m trying to test a CSS property (`ime-mode`) that activates the input method editor (IME) of the host operating system for specific form fields. To do this, I need to enable an IME on the host operating system.

I’ve figured out how to do so on Windows 7 and Mac OS X. However, on Windows XP, I’m in Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Languages > Details > Settings > Installed Services > Add, and I’m trying to work out if any of the default options under “Keyboard layout/IME” are actually IMEs.

I don’t have East Asian language support installed, so I can’t see any Japanese keyboards or IMEs (which is what I’ve used on Windows 7 and Mac OS X).

Are any of the built-in input options on Windows XP IMEs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn’t find any built-in IMEs, but there are two options for getting some.

1. I *believe* that checking the “Install files for complex script and right-to-left languages” option in Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Languages will install some IMEs. However, for this you need the disk that Windows came on, and I’m using Microsoft’s IE compatibility VMs.
2. You can install [the Microsoft Pinyin IME](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/zh-cn/details.aspx?familyid=2BF3CDF9-972F-4C57-9D01-40C19F27C746&displaylang=zh-cn).

There is also the [Office XP Global IME](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22917), but you need Microsoft Office installed for that to work.